# How to remove specific information from a line in txt

Tags: regex, text, replace, notepad++

I have a format like this in my txt file:

```
FirstName:Email:SecondName:Birthdate
```

An example: Jacky:jacky@jacky.com:8-1-1991

How can I remove the email from the line I believe its possible with reg exp's?

Comment: Replace `^(.*?:).*?:` with `$1`

Comment: @Lucas - not even close.

Comment: @pguardiario care to explain what's wrong with this?

Comment: @Lucas - the regexp works perfectly. By using non greedy matches, it is much more elegant, than what I suggested in my answer. It works even when there are three or four columns.

Answer (score 1):

There is no SecondName in your Jacky example. In the followingI assume that the lines are like this: `Jacky:jacky@jacky.com:SecondName:8-1-1991`.

Use Replace and check regulare expression in the dialogs lower left:

**Find**: `^([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*):([^:]*)$`

**Replace**: `\1:\3:\4`

If there is no :SecondName: in the data:

- leave out one of the `([^:]*):` (which matches a column up to the next ":")
- and replace with `\1:\3`

**Explanation**: `\1, \2, \3 and \4` refer to a part in the find regexp which is enclosed in parentheses. The regexp

- finds the four columns seperated by ":"
- makes the content available in `\1, ..., \4`
- and the replacement only skips the second column, which is your email column

Comment: Yup, that works too. But I'd use `[^:\n]` instead of `[^:]` just in case there could be invalid lines in the file. That way, the match won't be able to span multiple lines.